# Debugging: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a functioning `form_for` a bookmark (which is nested under Topics). When I attempt to go to the page, I see a **First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty** error. I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this.

Here's my code so far:

**Form in *topics_show***:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <%= form_for [@topic, @bookmark] do |b| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= b.label :url %>
      <%= b.text_field :url, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter URL Here" %>
      <%= b.submit "Save Topic", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**BookmarksController**:

```
def create
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @bookmark = Bookmark.new(bookmark_params)
 end

  def new
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @bookmark = Bookmark.new
    render :show
  end

 def bookmark_params
    params.require(:bookmark).permit(:url, :topic_id)
  end
```

**TopicsController**:

```
 def new
    @topic = Topic.new
  end


  def create
    @topic = Topic.new(topic_params)
    if @topic.save
      flash[:notice] = "Topic was successfully saved."
      redirect_to @topic
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Error saving topic. Try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def topic_params
    params.require(:topic).permit(:title)
  end
```

Lastly, I have bookmarks nested within topics in my routes.rb file.

I appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Can you add the code that is invoking your BookmarksController#new action to your question please?

Comment: Is this what you mean? This is in my topics.show:

`<div>
  <h3><%= @topic.title %></h3>
  <h6><%= @bookmark %></h6>
</div>`

Comment: no I mean the link that is initiating the display of the form.

Comment: That would be the `form_for` above in my topics_show view. The code is above. Thanks for your help, btw!

Comment: Your form_for is what will be rendered as a result of a call to your action... what I was asking for is the link that initiates that action.

Comment: Oh my mistake. I think you're looking for this:

`<div class="col-md-8">
  <%= form_for @topic do |t| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= t.label :title %>
      <%= t.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter Title Here" %>
      <%= t.submit "Save Topic", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>`